# InputMask on Continuous Form - how to modify only on the current record

Tags: ms-access, input-mask

I'm working in Access 2010.  I have a continuous form containing a list of password records.  The password field textbox contains the input mask of input mask = "password".  I created a button in my header to unmask the password field, but that affects ALL the records on the form.  I'd like only the current record in use to change the input mask to ".  I also tried adding an icon next to the password field so it appears on each row, but once again, the change is applied to every row.

I considered the Conditional Format function but that's only designed to change the color of the current record.

Comment: Can't. Programmatically setting a control's property affects all instances of control because there is only the one control.

Comment: Could use Conditional Formatting to dynamically change BackColor and ForeColor so control appears empty or blacked out.

Comment: Review https://sfmagazine.com/post-entry/october-2018-access-highlight-the-current-record/

Comment: You should never store passwords as clear text, only their hashes. Then there will be no need for showing these, neither masked nor unmasked.

Comment: I seen apps that allow user to 'show password'.

Answer (score 0):

Let the button open a popup form (or, even simpler, a message box) revealing the password.

That said, for users' passwords, this should not be an option. The only option should be to reset the password in case a user has forgot it.